# How do you create name badges in Google Docs with a background, preferably using Avery?

Tags: google-docs, mail-merge

I am trying to use Google Docs to create name badges that have a background image behind the text. Our company used to have Microsoft Suite and historically, we used the Mail Merge option within the Mailings tab of Microsoft Word. This was our go to for years. We have recently migrated to using Google and I have seen many articles pointing to the "add-ons" tab within Google Docs, using the option "Avery Label Merge". I have had many exchanges with Avery support and Avery support has noted that, though it appears to have an option to do so, there is no option to use the image as a background image.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Surely there has to be a way to create name badges that use a background image alternatively to the Mail Merge option in Microsoft.

Comment: I use Linix and this is a feature of the program gLables but there are alternatives. Take your pick from [this resource](https://alternativeto.net/software/glabels/?platform=windows)

Comment: Is the background image the same for all the name badges?

Comment: Yes the background would be the same.
However we do change the background per event. Thanks